# Resuming a count value when importing a list stored with pickle as well as viewing that list with Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, pickle, python-3.4

EDIT: I decided to use pickle and try that method..

The app I'm working with has a function that creates an invoice for a business. Each invoice is counted and numbered appropriately with the number of invoices created in order. This invoices are stored as dictionaries inside a list. This list is then exported with pickle to a file. Now, my problem is that I want to load that pickle file, load the list and keep saving on it following the order of invoice numbers, as well as viewing the orders already stored in the external file in the Listbox.

This would be the list the stores the dictionaries and loads the external file :

```
import os
import pickle  
file_path = "/Users/user1/Documents/storage/xoomdatabase.txt"
xoomDatabase = []

loadLis = open(file_path, "r")
dalis = pickle.load(loadLis)
loadLis.close()
xoomDatabase.append(dalis)
print(dalis)
```

This is the Listbox the displays all the invoices that are stored on the xoomDatabase list:

```
class AccessDatabase:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Imprint Plus Manager")
        self.master = master


        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        self.frame_header.config(height = 40, width = 100)
        self.frame_header.config(relief = RIDGE)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = "Ordenes").grid()

        self.frame_verDatabase = Listbox(master, selectmode = BROWSE)
        self.frame_verDatabase.insert(END, *Database.xoomDatabase) 
        self.frame_verDatabase.pack()

        self.frame_verDatabase.config(height = 70, width = 150)
```

Heres the function i'm using to pickle dump:

```
def closeApp(self):
        with open(file_path, "wb") as fout:
            pickle.dump(Database.xoomDatabase, fout)
        self.master.destroy()
```

To further explain what I want:
For example;
I created 4 invoices today that got numbered invoice #1, invoice #2, etc.
I saved the list with pickle.
Opened my app again, and now i want to keep creating invoices starting from the last number of invoice counted, so it would start saving from invoice #5, invoice #6, etc.
Also when I view the listbox, I would like to see all the invoices created starting from invoice #1.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i edited my post to better explain what i want..

Comment: I was thinking of appending the a var the calls the json file and then appends that data into the listbox. Will this work?

Comment: You could simply persist the count with pickle or something similar then start your invoice numbers from there or simply extract the last dict from the list and get the invoice number so you know what the lst num was

Comment: I want to try with pickle, but I'm having problems loading the pickle dump...

Comment: Maybe it would be better for what i want to use shelves?

Comment: Anything really once you persist the count, shelve will work fine, what happened with pickle?

Comment: I keep getting : dalis = pickle.load(loadLis)
EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: Did you dump it first?

Comment: yea with : with open(file_path, "wb") as fout:
            pickle.dump(Database.xoomDatabase, fout)

Comment: And opened it with rb?

Comment: My problem seems to be that I'm trying to load the dump before any data can be saved to it..

Comment: Good. What was wrong?

Comment: I was trying to load the dump when it had nothing on it. Now my problem is continuing the invoice number counter and having the dictionaries saved on the dump to load in my listbox everytime I run the app..

Comment: Also, my dump is overwriting any previous data saved..